# How to renew token in sts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I am using aws sts service to connect with amazon resources. I have the following java code for that purpose

```
 AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                        .roleArn(roleArm)
                        .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                        .build();
             
  AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
             
  sessionCredentials = roleResponse.credentials();
         
  stsCredentials = AwsSessionCredentials.create(
                     sessionCredentials.accessKeyId(),
                     sessionCredentials.secretAccessKey(),
                     sessionCredentials.sessionToken()); 
             
  provider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(stsCredentials);
```

At first I was under the impression that I didnt have to detect the token expiration and renew it at given time intervals (I thought the service would renew it itself) but it seems that the token expires after a certain time interval.

How do I detect and renew the token?

Comment: STS credentials can't renew, you need to generate new credentials using the code you have posted.

Comment: @jordanm but how do I know when to call the code above? Every hour? Every 3 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I detect and renew the token?

Your `AssumeRoleResponse` should give you [expiration](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sts/model/Credentials.html). So you have to monitor it, and when few minutes before your credentials expire, you have to create **new credentials** yourself. There is no automatic renew, unless you run your code on EC2 instance, ECS container or a lambda function. In that case, AWS take cares of this process.

Comment: Yes I am running the code on an ec2 instance but it tells me it cant connect to the resource after a while because the token is expired.

Comment: @user2175783 So you don't have to explicitly assume the role, if you are doing this for instance role. Obviously, if you are assummig any other role then instance role, you still have to manage it yourself.

Comment: Does it matter which provider I use? For example in the code above I am using StaticCredentialsProvider but not sure if it matters.

Comment: @user2175783 You would have to read up how [instance roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) work and how to use them transparently in your app.